# Настройка Visual Studio Code. Сворачивает теги

Tags: visual-studio-code

Имеется код вида:

```
    <input-select name="price" 
                       focus="focusonprice" 
                       ng-model="object.price" 
                       type="text" 
                       currency="object.currency" 
                       select="object.default_currency" 
                       choices="object.currency_choices"
                       errors="form.price.$error" 
                       label="[['Цена'|translate]]" 
                       id="offer-price">
    </input-select>
```

однако, после сохранения он трансформируется в:

```
    <input-select name="price" focus="focusonprice" ng-model="object.price" type="text" currency="object.currency" select="object.default_currency" choices="object.currency_choices" errors="form.price.$error" label="[['Цена'|translate]]" id="offer-price">
    </input-select>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы тег не сворачивался в 1 строку?

Comment: Если ответ правильный и помог, Вы должны отметить, как правильный. (c)

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно у себя в файле настроек `File > Preferences > Settings` или нажав <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> установить параметр `"editor.formatOnSave": false`, по умолчанию он установлен в `true`.